# Trouble With File Creating In Python

Tags: python

I am creating a program where you create a text file and it runs `ls` in the terminal to display the files that I have in that folder. My problem is that I have 2 folders. One is for the program itself, and one is for the text files that I create. By default, the text file saves to the folder that contains the program. here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import termcolor
import os
os.system("cd /home/marc/QuickJotTexts && ls")
print ""

title = raw_input("What Will Your Title Be? ")
print""

print "Your Title Is", title
text_file = open(title, "w")
print ""

text = raw_input("What Do You Want To Write In This Document? ")

text_file.write(text)
text_file.close()

text_file = open(title, "r")

print "YOU WROTE", text_file.read()

nub = raw_input("Is This Correct? y/n ")

if nub == "y":
    print "Ok, Bye :)"
    text_file.close()
if nub == "n":
    os.system("rm", title)
```

This is only a very small part of my code.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
text_file = open(title, "w")
```

which opens a file in your current directory, you should specify what path you want to save in

```
SAVEDIR = "/home/marc/saves"
text_file = open(os.path.join(SAVEDIR, title), "w")
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.system()` executes independently of your python interpreter. The interpreter doesn't actually change its working directory with that command, but rather [fires it off as a background process](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) and reports the exit code (hopefully, '0').

What you're looking for is `os.chdir()`.

Your question is adequately addressed in [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432924/python-change-the-scripts-working-directory-to-the-scripts-own-directory).