# How can I change the folder where a file is created in python?

Tags: python

I would like to change the folder where a file is created in my Python Script.

Just now I have the next line:

```
file = open("scraping.txt", "w")
```

but the problem is that scraping.txt is saved in the root folder and I would like to save it in the same folder where the script is.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if duplicate or just related: [Change the scripts working directory to the script's own directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432924/python-change-the-scripts-working-directory-to-the-scripts-own-directory).

Comment: related: [Retrieving python module path](http://stackoverflow.com/q/247770/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, python creates `scraping.txt` in the directory from where you invoke the script. In your case, you are invoking the script from root directory thats why file is created at root directory.

you can use `os.path.abspath(__file__)` for getting folder of your script.

```
import os
open(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__),'..','scraping.txt'),'w')
```

Comment: I have implemented this and it brings me another error in the next line: `file.write("URL\n")`

Comment: can you please try invoking your script with sudo if you are in unix/Mac?

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Ok, now it is working like a charm. The problem was that I was using " instead of `

Comment: i have also edited...in winsows dirname is different result when it's executed from different folder. You can use abspath and relative path from there..This should work now.

Comment: use `os.path.dirname` instead of `..`.

Comment: i was just getting name of the script folder instead of complete path of script folder in windows if executed from different directory than script...i have initially suggested dirname and later changed to abspath

Comment: it has nothing to do with `..`; try `open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'scraping.txt'), 'w')`. Note: `__file__` fails for symlinks, frozen executables, scripts that are run using `execfile()`. Here's how you could [get the script directory in more general case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22881871/4279)

Comment: i tried this:  print `os.path.dirname( __file__ )` and executed file from different directory: C:\Users\username>python Desktop\test.py; this gives Desktop as output where as i would expect C:\Users\username\Desktop as output. Thanks for letting me know about symlinks; it really helpful..

Answer (score 1):

Either add the path to the file:

```
file = open('/path/to/scraping.txt', 'w')
```

Or use the `os` module to change the directory:

```
import os
os.chdir('/path/to/')
file = open('scraping.txt', 'w')
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add the path :

```
file = open("/PATH/TO/YOUR/FOLDER/scraping.txt", "w")
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it automatically? I mean, that the program detects where the script is located and then write that file on the same folder.

Comment: you can move first to that directory and then run your script from there, it will create the file in the same place

Comment: I am looking for a more straightforward solution such as detecting the directory where the script is located and generate the .txt file in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

By default python creates file in you present working directory.
You can know your present working directory using:

import os

> > > os.getcwd()

Just change your directory to the desired one using:

> > > os.chdir('new/directory')

Now create file under your desired path.