# Supervisor - program's directory option not working

Tags: python, supervisord

I want to execute python script by supervisor.

I set up the directory option in supervisord.conf
and I used relative path in command option like this.

```
[supervisord]
http_port=/var/tmp/supervisor.sock ; (default is to run a UNIX domain socket server)
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB       ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10          ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info               ; (logging level;default info; others: debug,warn)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false              ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                 ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)
directory=/root             ; (default is not to cd during start)

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/tmp/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

[program:test]
directory=/root/test
command=python ./test.py
autostart=true
```

In python script, I used relative path like this.

```
textfile = open('./textfile')
```

I can successfully execute this python script by `python ./test.py` on `/root/test` directory.
But when I started supervisor, I got this error.

```
python: can't open file './test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Next, I used absolute path in command option of supervisor.conf like this.

```
[program:test]
directory=/root/test
command=python /root/test/test.py
```

And I got this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/test/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    textfile = open('./textfile')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './textfile'
```

Is there no way to set up the directory on where the script is executed?

Comment: You change `test.py` to change the pwd to that of the script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432924/python-change-the-scripts-working-directory-to-the-scripts-own-directory

Comment: This seems the easiest way to solve my issue, at least now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than using the absolute path to `textfile` in `test.py`, you can change the present working directory to that of the script by adding the following to `test.py` before calling `textfile = open('./textfile')`:

```
import os

abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname)
```

See [python: Change the scripts working directory to the script's own directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432924/python-change-the-scripts-working-directory-to-the-scripts-own-directory)