# How to find path to current .py file in Spyder (Anaconda)?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

**Set-up**

I run a script on my computer, located in the directory `Users/path/to/my/script.py`.

In the script, I use the path to the script, e.g.,

```
sub_path = 'Users/path/to/my/'
os.chdir(sub_path + 'other_script/')
```

As you can see, I define `sub_path` in the code 'manually'.

---

**Problem**

I don't want to define the `sub_path` manually, I'd rather have Python do it for me.

I'm looking for something similar to the code I use to obtain the current working directory: `os.getcwd()`, but then a code to obtain the directory of the current file.

I mainly find answers similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3283336/7326714), which says,

`os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`

but in the Spyder & Anaconda set-up, this generates a `NameError: name '__file__' is not defined`.

What can I do?

Comment: that's probably because you are running part of your code inside the ipython commandline. So the commandline doesn't have a `__file__` property. Use the play button to run the whole script and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You if you want to move back one folder/directory you use the `..` in your file path.

`os.chdir('../other_scripts/')`

will work. You may fine it helpful to view [this](https://superuser.com/questions/153165/what-does-represent-while-giving-path) or [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)).
If you want to move from where you currently are you can use `'./new_dir/'`. If you want to automate how to find other files you may want to read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724693/find-a-file-in-python) which says to use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory) may be the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Mark8888 [pointed out](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3154#issuecomment-216838105) to run the whole script (run file (F5)) instead of just pieces of the script

this way multiple approaches should work to get the script file location and change the current working directory

```
import os
# directory of script file
print(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
# change current working directory
os.chdir(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
# current working directory
print(os.getcwd())
```

also

```
import os
import sys
# directory of script file
print(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])))
# change current working directory
os.chdir(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])))
# current working directory
print(os.getcwd())
```

Answer (score 0):

I add the following lines to any script I run in case I need to access data relative to the location of the script

```
import sys
script = sys.argv[0]
print(script)
'C:/SomeFolder/A_Subfolder/CurrentlyRunningScript.py'  # changed obviously
```

Comment: Thank you for thinking with me. Your solution doesn't work for me, it gives me a `script = ''`.

Comment: It only works if you are running a script from within a python IDE, I suspect then you are launching python.exe 'c:/somescript.py'

Answer (score -2):

First, save your Jupyter Notebook.  Second, locate the directory your Jupyter Notebook is stored in. Thirdly, ensure that your Jupyter Notebook and CSV file are in the same place.

Comment: The OP is asking about how to the current file path in Spyder, not in the notebook.