# How to get the directory of a current script on Spyder (without using '__file__')?

Tags: python, directory, anaconda, spyder

When I open Spyder (version 4.1.4), it opens a script that I was previously working with. However, the directory is set to `'C:\\Users\\UserName'` (this is what I get with `os.getcwd()`).

I like to change the directory to where the script is, but I couldn't find a simple way to get the directory of the script and use `os.chdir(path)`.

As it's mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50216508/how-to-find-path-to-current-py-file-in-spyder-anaconda), `os.path.dirname(__file__)` gives `NameError: name '__file__' is not defined` when I run it on Spyder console, and I like to get the path without running the whole script.

In Spyder, what command(s) can I use to find a currently opened script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found a solution either. This is the way I deal with it on Windows:

1. Select and comment the whole script (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>)
2. Run file (<kbd>F5</kbd>)
3. Uncomment or undo (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>).

At least in my case, the current directory changes to that of the script.