# How do I make CMake run a python script before building, in order to generate files for my project to be used in the build?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a python script that parses all of the C++ source files in the project's directory, looks for some stuff in the files, and then generates a file.  This python script works fine, but I want it to automatically run before building my C++ project.

So basically, I want this python script to run before every build, so if any .h or .cpp files have been changed.  I'd also like it to run if the python script itself has been changed.  I have the python script in question, `genenums.py`, in the same directory as my C++ source files such as `main.cpp`, etc.

I've tried experimenting with `add_custom_command` based on documentation, but I can't get cmake to ever run this python script in any instance.  I'm not sure how to make this work right, as I'm new to cmake.

Here's my current cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(enum_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include_directories(include)

find_package( PythonInterp 2.7 REQUIRED )
find_package( PythonLibs 2.7 REQUIRED )

add_custom_command(
 COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} genenums.py
 DEPENDS genenums.py $(CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR)
 OUTPUT enums.h
 WORKING_DIRECTORY $(CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR)
 COMMENT "Generating enums"
)

add_executable(enum_test main.cpp test.h test.cpp)
```

Comment: EXECUTE_PROCESS (COMMAND PYTHON .. ) , have you tried using this ?

Comment: @ArchieYalakki I just tried it, but the script doesn't run, just like almost everything I've tried.  I have something that runs now, but it runs in parallel to the build and cmake kills the script before it can do much anyway.

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/execute_process.html

Comment: @ArchieYalakki I tested it again since you insist, but it still has the issue of cmake terminating the process before it can complete.  It is also running during the cmake configuration I think, not before the build.  It's not executing before the build at all, which is when I need it to run.

Comment: I have the impression that your code is almost correct, with the small but important caveat that `enums.h` must be listed in the `add_executable` call. Otherwise CMake will figure that no one actually needs the file, so why bother building it. This might seem like silly bureaucracy but it starts to make sense when you consider that your project may declare many targets and only a fraction of them might require this file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, I have a foolproof, non-ugly way to have cmake run any kind of commands right before a build to build a dependency, waiting until the commands are done before doing the build.

```
add_custom_target(
 run ALL
 COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/genenums.py ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
 BYPRODUCTS enums.h
 COMMENT "Generating enums"
)

add_dependencies(enum_test run)
```

The two key parts are the `add_custom_target` and `add_dependencies`, both are required to make this work.  Place both after the `add_executable` in `CMakeLists.txt`.  `enum_test` refers to the target created by `add_executable` (the first name in its list), so you'd set that to your project's name.

You can name the custom target to whatever you like (I used `run` here) by changing the `run` in both `add_custom_target` and `add_dependencies` to something else.

There's one additional catch with `add_custom_target`... `WORKING_DIRECTORY` in that did nothing for my python script.  Even when I tried to set the `WORKING_DIRECTORY` to `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`, the script executed in the default `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` anyway.

So for this one catch, whatever commands you're using need to be able to take a command line argument of `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` and use that to operate in the source directory properly (assuming that's your goal).  That's why I have `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` at the end of this line:

```
 COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/genenums.py ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
```

Here's the full `CMakeLists.txt` with the working setup, should be fairly easy to adapt to any particular project's `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(enum_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include_directories(include)

find_package( PythonInterp 2.7 REQUIRED )

add_executable(enum_test enums.h main.cpp test.h test.cpp)

add_custom_target(
 run ALL
 COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/genenums.py ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
 BYPRODUCTS enums.h
 COMMENT "Generating enums"
)

add_dependencies(enum_test run)
```

Comment: I believe you don't need `find_package( PythonLibs 2.7 REQUIRED )`, as you do not link agains Python

Comment: @R2RT Thanks, I'll remove that

Comment: Great answer. Just to add, you don't need the extra "working directory" argument, you can do `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432924/python-change-the-scripts-working-directory-to-the-scripts-own-directory

Comment: THANK YOU!  I was banging my head against the (it turns out) non-portable PRE_BUILD variant of add_custom_command.  This works just how I wanted.

Comment: Thanks you very much, turns out order of writing the add_custom_target is critical.
Meaning that the order must be:
add_executable/library()
add_custom_target()
add_dependencies()

I tried to write
add_custom_target()
add_executable()
..
But that failed depending on timing, if I use -j 25 for example then it sometimes succeeded.