# Why is the output of readline() blank in a non-empty text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, directory, readlines

I am running python 3.7 in Wing IDE as an administrator.

The python file is in the same folder (Documents) as the textdoc file.

This is the python code I have:

```
file = open("textdoc.txt", "r")

print(file.readlines())

file.close()
```

This is the content of the notepad (.txt) file called textdoc:

```
blue

red

green
```

When I run the program, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 2, line 3
builtins.FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'textdoc.txt'
```

Another issue is that while I am able to create and write to files in Python using the write mode, I can't actually find the text file that was created anywhere in case I want to edit it manually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python: Change the scripts working directory to the script's own directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432924/python-change-the-scripts-working-directory-to-the-scripts-own-directory)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your two questions are actually the same, that is, your python execute your code at another dir. Try to execute it in the command-line:

```sh
cd /path/to/your/program
# Check if your file is there
# For windows:
DIR
# For Linux or MacOS:
ls
# Execute python script:
python pyscript.py
```