# How to read a file in Python function and call that function from some other python file?

Tags: python

Folder structure:

```
MainFolder
    __init__.py
    FolderA
        Config.json
        ConfigHelper.py
        testA.py
    FolderB
        Test.py
```

ConfigHelper.py file:

```
import json
class ConfigHelper:
    def read_config(self):
        fileName = "Config.json"
        with open(fileName, "r") as jsonfile:
            return json.load(jsonfile)
```

When calling ConfigHelper.read_config() function from FolderB-->Test.py file , then
Getting Error:  No such file or directory: 'config.json'
But if calling it from TestA.py file, No error is coming.
Look like it is taking path relative from the calling place.
Please tell me , How I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the full path to the file. You are right that it is looking for the relative path. When you are just passing the `Config.json` path it is looking in your current working directory for this.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in FolderB there is no `config.json` file there.

Solutions

- Run your script from `MainFolder` and pass correct path (FolderA/config.json).
- Add folders to path, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath).
- Change working directory to `FolderB` before trying to read `config.json`, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432924/python-change-the-scripts-working-directory-to-the-scripts-own-directory).

Answer (score 0):

```
 path = os.getcwd()
 print("Current Directory", path)
 filepath = path + "/MainFolder/FolderA/Config.json"
```

Gave Full Path as above to fix the problem.